# Postgres function not translating correctly in jooq

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a Postgres function function_X() with a return value of a type rowtype. When I generate the JOOQ artifacts- the function is not generated under the gen/routiens classes, as it should; but is available to be called in the Routines.java class.

Snippet from the Routines.java class

```
public static FunctionX functionX(Integer[] input) {
        return FunctionX.FUNCTION_X.call(input);
```

I am calling this function using the below code

```
    List<FunctionX> lst = dsl.select().from(Routines.functionX(arr)).fetchInto(FunctionX.class);
```

This is generating a SQL

```
jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select "function_X"."function_X" from "dbo"."function_X"(?::int[])]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column function_X.function_X does not exist
  Position: 8
```

Why is a select * not being generated?

JOOQ version 3.71. Postgres 9.5

Comment: do you really have a schema named `dbo`?

Comment: Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: There have been many fixes in recent jOOQ versions - yours is already 2 years old. Please upgrade to 3.9.5 and try again.

Comment: It didn't work after upgrade.

Comment: OK, thanks for trying. Could you post your PostgreSQL `CREATE FUNCTION` statement including all the required types?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lucas. I went ahead and did an inline call to the function and wrote my own mapper. I can't really post the code here- proprietary . Its a 1200 line db function with atleast 70 attributes that are returned :(